# Android Paging3 Varying Page Size

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-paging-3

How can I use the paging3 library where each page can vary in size?

I am trying to show a calendar where each page would be represented by a week, and each week can have 0 to n meetings in it.

I figured I can use today's day as the paging key in my DataSource for the initial load and ±7 days for the previous/next pages, eg:

```
class CalendarPagingSource @Inject constructor(
    private val calendarApi: CalendarApi,
) : RxPagingSource<ZonedDateTime, Meeting>() {

    override fun loadSingle(params: LoadParams<ZonedDateTime>): Single<LoadResult<ZonedDateTime, Meeting>> { 
        val page = params.key ?: ZonedDateTime.now()
        val startDate = page.format(ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))

        return calendarApi
            .myMeetings(startDate)
            .map { toLoadResult(page, it) }
            .onErrorReturn { LoadResult.Error(it) }
    }

    private fun toLoadResult(key: ZonedDateTime, entries: List<Meeting>): LoadResult<ZonedDateTime, Meeting> {
        val now = ZonedDateTime.now()

        // Do not load more than 90 days before and after today
        return LoadResult.Page(
            data = entries,
            prevKey = if (now.minusDays(90L).isBefore(key)) key.minusDays(DATE_RANGE) else null,
            nextKey = if (now.plusDays(90L).isAfter(key)) key.plusDays(DATE_RANGE) else null 
        )
    }
}
```

But I am facing an issue where I can not know ahead of time how many meetings a specific week will have.

```
class CalendarRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val pagingSource: CalendarPagingSource
) {

    fun myMeetings(): Observable<PagingData<Meeting>> {
        return Pager(
            config = PagingConfig(
                pageSize = ???, 
                enablePlaceholders = false
            ),
            pagingSourceFactory = { pagingSource }
        ).observable
    }
}
```

Is there a way around where I don't have to specify the pageSize and just do the paging just using the paging key (in this case a ZonedDateTime) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pageSize` is just a hint that is sent to `LoadParams`, paging3 can handle variable page sizes just fine and your `PagingSource` dorsn't need to respect what `loadSize` is requested.

Just put whatever number you want to appear in `LoadParams.loadSize`. Generally it could be something based on the size of your viewport so you can estimate how many days of events to load.